# Normal quit applescript running terminal nc command

Tags: applescript

I made an applescript that listens to a certain port. When it receives "start", the computer starts recording from the webcam, when it receives "stop", it stops recording.

Now the problem is that I always have to force quit this application. Due to the repeat statement? Is there a way to circumvent this? I read something about an idle handler, but it is important for my application to keep running (without a user clicking etc).

```
set recording to 0
repeat
set test to (do shell script "nc -l 2700") as string

if test = "start" and recording = 0 then
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        activate
        new movie recording
        document "Movie Recording" start
        set recording to 1
        delay 2
    end tell
else if test = "stop" and recording = 1 then
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        document "Movie Recording" stop
        set pad to path to desktop folder as string
        set naam to (do shell script "date +%s") as integer
        set extension to ".mov"
        set all to pad & naam & extension
        export document "Untitled" in file all using settings preset "720p"
        delay 1
        close document "Untitled" saving no
        set recording to 0
    end tell
end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add a "quit" message in addition to "start" and "stop" ?

Answer (score 0):

You were right about the [idle handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html). The return statement specifies how many seconds should pass before the handler is called. Make sure you save the script as a stay-open application.

```
on idle
    --insert your code
    beep
    return 10
end idle
```